# Having a problem with Field validation in Ncurses form

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

I'm having some problems with field validation in a ncurses form, that hopefully someone have an explanation for.
The issue is with the below attached code. Specifically in the field called 'AuthorityCode' in the function `validateField()`.
The ENUM `Auth_codes` is set to it's three values and when entering correct values (one of the enum values) it works fine. It also validates most of the incorrect values (values not in the ENUM). However, for some reason it accepts a single number '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' or '8' in the field, but not a '7' or '9'. It doesn't seem like any single letter gets accepted and also not any combination of more than one number, only the above numbers.
All the other validations (including other enums), seems to be working as they should.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour or can find a problem in my code?

```
const char* Auth_codes[]
{ "Add", "Update", "Delete" };

const char* Return_codes[]
{ "Accepted", "Denied" };

const char* Priorities[]
{ "3", "5", "6", "8" };


void createForm(WINDOW *win_body, vector<string> &input, int selection)
{
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int i;
    int cury = 0;
    int curx = 1;
    int nb_fields;
    WINDOW *inner;

    formClose = false;

    getmaxyx(win_body, rows, cols);

    nb_fields = input.size()
    
    fields = (FIELD**) malloc(sizeof(FIELD *) * (nb_fields + 1));
    assert(fields);

    for (i = 0; i < nb_fields; i++)
    {
            fields[i] = new_field(1, 10, cury, curx, 0, 0);
            assert(fields[i] != NULL);
            set_field_buffer(fields[i], 0, "");
            field_opts_on(fields[i], O_ACTIVE);
            field_opts_on(fields[i], O_EDIT);
            field_opts_off(fields[i], O_AUTOSKIP);
            set_field_back(fields[i], A_UNDERLINE);
            validateField(fields[i], input[i].c_str()); // Set correct field validation based on label value
            curx = 1; // Set position for next label field
            cury = cury + 1; // Next line

    }
    
    fields[i] = NULL;
    form = new_form(fields);
    assert(form != NULL);
    win_form = derwin(win_body, rows - 10, cols - 4, 3, 2);
    box(win_form, 0, 0);
    assert(form != NULL && win_form != NULL);
    set_form_win(form, win_form);
    inner = derwin(win_form, form->rows + 1, form->cols + 1, 1, 1);
    assert(inner != NULL);
    set_form_sub(form, inner);

    assert(post_form(form) == E_OK);
    assert(post_menu(menu) == E_OK);

    refresh();
    wrefresh(win_body);
    wrefresh(win_form);

    while (formClose == false)
        process_input(getch());

    delete_form();

}


void validateField(FIELD *field, const char *name)
{
    if (strcmp(name, "AdviceNoteNumber") == 0)
    {
        set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
                TYPE_ALNUM,     // Type to associate
                0);             // Minimum field width
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, "AssignmentId") == 0 || strcmp(name, "AssignmentReferenceId") == 0
            || strcmp(name, "TransportAssignmentId") == 0)
    {
        set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
                TYPE_INTEGER,   // Type to associate
                0,              // Number of padding zeroes
                10000,          // Min value
                99999);         // Max value
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, "AuthorityCode") == 0)
    {
        set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
                TYPE_ENUM,      // Type to associate
                Auth_codes,     // List of values
                0,              // Not case sensitive
                1);             // Unique prefix
    }
    else if (strcmp(name, "ReturnCode") == 0)
    {
        set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
                TYPE_ENUM,      // Type to associate
                Return_codes,   // List of values
                0,              // Not case sensitive
                1);             // Unique prefix

    }
    else if (strcmp(name, "Priority") == 0)
    {
        set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
                TYPE_ENUM,      // Type to associate
                Priorities,     // List of values
                0,              // Not case sensitive
                1);             // Unique prefix
    }
```

Comment: If you focus your mind, laser sharp, on one simple question, the problem should be very obvious. How do you expect `set_field_type` to know exactly how many values there are, in the enum field? As per `set_field_type`'s documentation, that parameter is just a `char **`. How could `set_field_type` possibly know that you're passing it four values. Or three? Or ten billion? Once you figure out what's missing, you'll know exactly what to do.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not sure I follow your reasoning. The documentaion for set_field_type and TYPE_ENUM clearly states: "_Accept one of a specified set of strings._" according to [link](https://linux.die.net/man/3/field_arg). I can't see the importance of how many values is in the enum, if the entered value isn't in the enum it should not validate. I haven't checked how curses library handles the enum when specified, but the expected result as far as I can understand is that the entered value should be present in the enum to be able to validate, regardless of amount of values?

Comment: Yes, but the library certainly needs to know ***how many*** values are there. Are there three enum values it needs to check? Or ten? Or ten million? If all you have a `char **`, and no other piece of information, how you explain how the library would know that this `char **` parameter points to exactly four strings? Please point your finger to the line in your code that does that. This is the "importance of how many values is in enum". it is a very important piece of information that the library must know, and you have not told the library how many enums there are. Without it, hilarity ensues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, had to go get the source code for ncurses (v.5.9) to check how the number of values in the `char**` was solved:
`kp = kwds;`
`while (kp && (*kp++))`
`cnt++;`
`argp->count = cnt;`
And that is why there isn't an option to specify the number of values in the call to `set_field_type`, it gets calculated in the called library function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I understand your point in a way, there has to be a way for the called function to know how many values there are to evaluate, but that was not the question. Plus there is nothing mentioned in the documentation about an argument regarding number of values (because it get calculated in library), there's just the `char** keywords`, `bool checkcase` and `bool checkunique` specified as arguments for this type. So your comment are really not very helpful.

Comment: No it was not a question, it is self-evident. Yes, the documentation does not explicitly state that, it's an omission but it was obvious that the library function must know how many `char *` it needs to check. It can't just keep incrementing the pointer, comparing the field's value to the pointer. It can't magically know the size of the array you're passing to it, and the number of pointers in it. C++ does not work this way. A null pointer was the only logical option. I never used this function myself, but I immediately realized that and my comment was prompting you to figure it out yourself.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But how does my figuring out the number of values help me? It doesn't explaining why it validates the single numbers in the field when they are not specified in the `char**`. Guess I'll just have to run the ncurses library through the debugger and find the answer myself, now that I have the source code. Doesn't seem like I'm going to get any insights or help here...

Comment: You are not passing to this function a null-terminated `char **` array, is that really not obvious? `const char* Priorities[]
{ "3", "5", "6", "8" };` -- do you see a `NULL` pointer anywhere here? You're passing a pointer to this, here. So, the ncurses function goes off looking for the null pointer, gets past the first four, and keeps looking, and looking, and looking. It starts reading other memory locations and interpreting them as pointers. It may crash, or it may find some garbage that it interprets as a valid enum value. Which matches ***exactly*** the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Now this was some helpful information! It suddenly became very clear and I feel somewhat bad for being rude... Had a fever and were overall annoyed yesterday. Could you perhaps put this last comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 set_field_type(field,   // Field to alter
            TYPE_ENUM,      // Type to associate
            Priorities,     // List of values
            0,            
            1);             // Unique prefix
```

The third parameter to `set_field_type` is a list of acceptable enum values, specified as a `char **`.

That can't be a list of pointers of some unspecified size. Clearly, the number of acceptable enum values, the number of pointers here, has to be defined in some form or fashion. It is not explicitly called out in `set_field_type`s documentation how the ***number*** of acceptable enum values is defined, this is just a `char **` parameter. But it is an accepted practice, in C and C++, to assume that a list of pointers is terminated by a `NULL` pointer; part of a textbook's typical definition of what `NULL` pointer means falls, somewhat, within those boundaries. `set_field_type`'s documentation implies this.

```
const char* Priorities[]=
{ "3", "5", "6", "8" };
```

The parameter is a list of four `char *`s, that gets passed as is. By the time it makes it into `set_field_type` it's just some `char **` value. There's nothing here that explicitly defines it as four pointers, so `set_field_type` tries to figure out how many enum values there is, starts looking here, counts four pointers, then keeps counting, and counting, forging ahead into random memory, attempting to interpret each value as one `char *` after another, until it hits something that it thinks is a `NULL` value, somewhere, and in the meantime attempts to interpret each intermediate value as a `char *`, pointing to somewhere.

If it doesn't crash by now, it'll start seeing phantom valid enum values, leading to [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: Love the link to _Nasal Deamons_! Thanks for the help by the way, even though I was a little slow in the beginning. It works like a charm now!

Comment: That's quite all right. I did not mind. If I just came out and said, oh, just stick a NULL pointer at the end of the list, you would've just taken it on face value as a given, and without having a deeper understanding of how things work. Well, now you do, and I think that the additional insight you gained from this excersize will be helpful in the future. Which was my intent. I don't like handing out answers directly. I prefer helping other people think for themselves and figure everything out on their own.